# Change default user configuration file location

Tags: home, profile

If possible, how can I change the default location the system looks to for files such as:

- .bashrc
- .bash_history
- .bash_profile
- .cshrc
- .hushlogin
- .tcshrc

I run Plesk and the default user home directory for plesk users is `/var/www/vhosts/$domain/`, where they FTP into. The custom users I create for other tasks goto `/home/$user/` as I like, and I want to store the configuration / command log files there away from user access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the system that looks for these files, but `bash`, `csh` and `tcsh` when they are your login shell.

If these accounts need these files (not for FTP but for interactive sessions) what you can try to do is update `/etc/bash.bashrc` with  a test:

```
if [[ "$HOME" == /var/www/vhosts/* ]]; then
  ALTHOME=/home/plesk
  . $ALTHOME/.bashrc
  . $ALTHOME/.bash_profile
  HISTFILE=$ALTHOME/.bash_history
fi
```

Although starting bash scripts will probably cause problems as they do not find `~/.bash_profile` that way.

Similar set-ups would be needed for `csh` and `tcsh` (do you really have users want those as login shells?)

If you start experimenting with `/etc/bash.bashrc` make sure you have a backup and keep a terminal or two open where you are logged in as root to copy the backup back in place in case you manage to lock yourself out, through an error in that file.

Comment: What about changing the `.viminfo` and `.hushlogin` locations?

Comment: @BrianGraham I have no idea where `.hushlogin` comes from, I don't have it on my system, so you have to figure that one out yourself. `.viminfo` can be suppressed or its position altered by a simple alias or function to start `vim` with the `-i` option.

Comment: I got the redirected vim working, I settled with turning `PrintMotd` in the sshd_config file. Thanks